# bidirectional uniform cost search

Tags: algorithm

I need to get optimal paths using a bidirectional uniform cost search.

I am really struggling with this, because neither an intersection of the frontier nor an intersection of the explored nodes suffices to guarantee an optimal result.

I think I might just run bidirectional until the explored regions intersect, and then limit one of the searches to the explored nodes of the other.

Is there anything else that will guarantee optimal paths, because I'd like a better performance gain.

Comment: Good question, hope we can get an answer to this one :)